# 11.10 to 12.04: update manager can't find 12.04

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I've got 11.10 and have fully updated it but the option to upgrade to 12.04 just isn't coming up. I even tried to update via terminal. Do I have to change something? (I'm fairly new to Ubuntu/Linux)

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 

sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

sudo do-release-upgrade
```